# PostgreSQL: how do you SELECT DISTINCT relations and order by different fields depending on WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, distinct, case

Each account is associated with one person and one type of account. I want to SELECT a distinct subset of accounts. In order to be selected the accounts have meet at least one of two criteria. If an account occurs twice

I want to order this result set based on two different fields. This was my attempt:

```
Select DISTINCT a.*
FROM people AS p
JOIN accounts AS a
ON a.people_id = p.id
JOIN type_account AS t
ON t.type_id = a.id
WHERE t.id IN(1,3,5)
OR p.id IN(2,4,6)
ORDER BY(CASE
         WHEN p.id IN(2,4,6) THEN p.updated_at
         WHEN t.id IN(1,3,5) THEN p.created_at) AS position
```

And I got this error: `SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

If I move the case statement to the select it possible for one account (associated with different people) to appear in the results twice, i.e. once when the first where clause is met and twice when the second where clause is met. In this case the accounts will be appearing twice in the result set.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this one. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move your CASE statement(s) into the SELECT clause, then order on their position:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN p.id IN(2,4,6) THEN p.updated_at
        WHEN t.id IN(1,3,5) THEN p.created_at
    END AS position,
    DISTINCT a.*
FROM people AS p
JOIN accounts AS a
ON a.people_id = p.id
JOIN type_account AS t
ON t.type_id = a.id
WHERE t.id IN(1,3,5)
OR p.id IN(2,4,6)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: But it possible for one account (associated with different people) to appear in the results twice, i.e. once when the first where clause is met and twice when the second where clause is met. In this case the accounts will be appearing twice in the result set.

Comment: So maybe you want a sub-query? I'm having a hard time fully grasping your requirements.

Comment: My requirements are that I only want one account in the results set.

Comment: Adding a `LIMIT 1` will easily accomplish that. I don't know if that will return the _correct_ account, though.

Comment: the correct account at least in terms of my current task is the one with the higher position value (the case statement)

Comment: Ah, then a `LIMIT 1` should work, in combination with sorting by DESC order. I updated my answer. Please let me know if this doesn't address your needs.

Comment: @Flimzy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1271/discussion-between-spencer-and-flimzy)